# Is this Asbestos?

Tags: asbestos, cement-board

I've found this flat panel in my garden (1 x 1.5 meters, thickness approximately 0.5 cm):  Is this Asbestos?
[image]
[image]

I'm in Bali where asbestos cement is still widely used. It's not friable.

Comment: The photos are private and we can't view them.  Try uploading them to imgur.com or change the permissions.

Comment: Since you've copywritten your photos and disabled downloading, we can't include them in your question. Try uploading somewhere like imgur.com so we can add them here.

Comment: With those long fibres, it looks more like hair and plaster than asbestos. Try burning one of the fibres by holding a match under it.

Comment: Are the pictures visible to everybody now? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could order an Asbestos test kit online, and find out.  The results are probably as accurate, if not more accurate than the answers you'll get from a random community of people on the internet.

[PRO-LAB®](http://www.prolabinc.com/index.html) offers just such an [Asbestos Test Kit](http://www.prolabinc.com/asbestos-test-kits.asp).

<sup><sub>*I have no affiliation with PRO-LAB® or any of it's products, and do not recommend or endorse any of their products or services.  This was simply the first product I found while searching the internet for "asbestos test kit"*</sub></sup>

Comment: Searching online it looks like TRANSITE HT ..what do you think? http://www.flickr.com/photos/asbestos_pix/4363427581/lightbox/

Comment: I think your fibers are smaller.  fibre cement and asbestos cement products look similar. I don't think you can tell by looking.