# Asbestos in wall?

Tags: asbestos, diy-vs-pro

Was removing wallpaper, there's a gap between the doorframe and wall, does this look like asbestos?

[image: Asbestos?]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this Asbestos?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/31138/is-this-asbestos)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This will likely be closed soon as a duplicate. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot tell by looking.  Many non-asbestos products look like asbestos and asbestos itself appears very differently in different products.

The only safe approach is to have it tested before disturbing it in any way.

Comment: "assume yes until proven otherwise"